# Cannot access files copied from another system

Tags: file-permissions, files, permissions

I brought Segate FreeAgent Go drive yesterday. I copied some Virtual Server hdds from my colleague's hard disk to mine. Now if I try to run VM it says

```
The virtual machine configuration could not be added. User does not have 
sufficient access rights.
```

If I try to modify permissions from properties I get error that I don't have access to file/folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have permission to access these files, therefore when you try and alter the permissions you get that error.

If you are an administrative level user, you will need to take ownership of the files. To do so go into the permissions tab, like you did before then click the advanced button. In the page that opens up, click the owner tab. In here select the account you want to own the account (most likely your account) and click ok. Click ok again to exit the permissions menu. You should then be able to access the file or change any permissions you wish.

You don't state what OS you are using, note that some Home versions of Windows OS's don't have the permissions tab to allow you to do this.

Comment: Exactly @Sam. I've installed Windows 7 and then Virtual Server 2005 R2 (a real pain in the ....) and I totally forgot this simple stuff!! Thanks for helping.